# <div><ul><li><div> SCRAPING RUBY with REGEX /w

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, regex-group

I am looking to do scraping of the website https://www.bananatic.com/es/forum/games/

and extract the tags "name", "views" and "replies".
I have a big problem to get the non-empty content of the "name" tag. Can you help me?
I need to save only the elements that do have text.

This is my code, I have three variables:

- **per** save what is inside the  ***replies***.
- **pir** save what is inside the  ***views***
- **res** saves what is inside the  ***names.***

Each array should contain only the elements that they have. something but in the  ***names*** the writings **[" "]** are saved and I want them not to be saved in my array.
[image]

```
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'pp'
    require 'csv'


    unless File.readable?('data.html')
      url = 'https://www.bananatic.com/de/forum/games/'
      data = URI.open(url).read
      File.open('data.html', 'wb') { |f| f << data }
    end
    data = File.read('data.html')
    document = Nokogiri::HTML(data)


    per = document.xpath('//div[@class="replies"]/text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]')
                  .map { |node| node.to_s[/\d+/] }

    p per

    pir = document.xpath('//div[@class="views"]/text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]')
                  .map { |node| node.to_s[/\w+/] }

    p pir

    links2 = document.css('.topics ul li div')
    res = links2.map do |lk|
      name = lk.css('.name  p a').inner_text
      [name]
    end
    p res
```

To fix it I have added a regular expression, however I have failed in the attempt.
I just replace **.inner_text**with **.to_s[/\w+/]**, but I don't get it.
[image]

Now I have an array with null values ​​and some letters ***"a"*** that I don't know where they appear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Might Help [XPath](https://devhints.io/xpath) and [CSS](https://devhints.io/css).

For your CSS check this out: https://kittygiraudel.github.io/selectors-explained/

The following will get you what you are looking for

```
document.xpath('//div[@class="topics"]/ul/li//div[@class="name"]/a[@class="js-link avatar"]/text()').map {|node| node.to_s.strip}`.
```

If you want to understand where your array is coming from take 1 step back and just print out `lk.css('.name  p a').to_s` but the real issue is your selectors are just off.

All that being said looking at the construct of the page you would be better off with something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://www.bananatic.com/de/forum/games/"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(url))
# Set a root node set to start from
topics = doc.xpath('//div[@class="topics"]/ul/li')

# loop the set 
details = topics.filter_map do |topic| 
  next unless topic.at_xpath('.//div[@class="name"]') # skip ones without the needed info
  # Map details into a Hash
  {name: topic.at_xpath('.//div[@class="name"]/a[@class="js-link avatar"]/text()').to_s.strip,
   post_year: topic.at_xpath('.//div[@class="name"]/text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]').to_s[/\d{4}/],
   replies: topic.at_xpath('.//div[@class="replies"]/text()').to_s.strip, 
   views: topic.at_xpath('.//div[@class="views"]/text()').to_s.strip 
  }
end
```

The result of `details` would be:

```
[{:name=>"MrCasual2502", :post_year=>"2016", :replies=>"0", :views=>"236"},
 {:name=>"MrCasual2502", :post_year=>"2016", :replies=>"0", :views=>"164"},
 {:name=>"EdgarAllen", :post_year=>"2022", :replies=>"0", :views=>"1"},
 {:name=>"RAMONVC", :post_year=>"2022", :replies=>"0", :views=>"0"},
 {:name=>"RAMONVC", :post_year=>"2022", :replies=>"0", :views=>"1"},
 {:name=>"tokyobreez", :post_year=>"2021", :replies=>"2", :views=>"18"},
 {:name=>"matrix12334", :post_year=>"2022", :replies=>"0", :views=>"2"},
 {:name=>"juggalohomie420", :post_year=>"2017", :replies=>"3", :views=>"89"},
 {:name=>"Imas86", :post_year=>"2022", :replies=>"2", :views=>"2"},
 {:name=>"SmilesImposterr", :post_year=>"2021", :replies=>"1", :views=>"17"},
 {:name=>"bebb", :post_year=>"2019", :replies=>"7", :views=>"22"},
 {:name=>"IMBANANAZ", :post_year=>"2016", :replies=>"1", :views=>"4"},
 {:name=>"IWantSteamKeys", :post_year=>"2021", :replies=>"1", :views=>"4"},
 {:name=>"gamormoment", :post_year=>"2021", :replies=>"1", :views=>"47"},
 {:name=>"Lovestruck", :post_year=>"2021", :replies=>"3", :views=>"46"},
 {:name=>"KillerBotAldwin1", :post_year=>"2021", :replies=>"1", :views=>"95"},
 {:name=>"purplevestynstr", :post_year=>"2020", :replies=>"1", :views=>"13"},
 {:name=>"Janabanana", :post_year=>"2021", :replies=>"3", :views=>"3"},
 {:name=>"apache724", :post_year=>"2017", :replies=>"3", :views=>"33"},
 {:name=>"MrsSue66", :post_year=>"2021", :replies=>"1", :views=>"38"}]
```

Comment: @CindyAdrianaBohrquezSantana okay then target that via `'.//div[@class="name"]/p/a/text()'`. See we target the div by class and then just walk down to the text `p` -> `a` -> `text()`

Comment: Your css could be changed to `'.topics > ul > li div.name > p > a'` to obtain the same concept